# "[ expression || expression ]" causes [: missing `]' error while running shell script

Tags: shell

```
if [ "$USER" != "root" || "$USER" != "XYZ" ]; then
echo succesful log
fi
```

Error is for the above line. How do i solve this

Comment: Are you sure that's the line in question? That error normally happens on a line where the closing `]` does not have spaces before/after it correctly (it doesn't need one between it and the semi-colon but does between it and the contents of the test).

Comment: yes. I am facing error on  that line only

Comment: i tried removing whitespaces but got the below error
root!=XYZ: command not found

Comment: @SheldonNeilson, that whitespace is entirely necessary. `[ $foo!=$bar ]` is always true, so long as `foo` and `bar` expand to single words in shell, since `[ "$x" ]` is equivalent to `[ -n "$x" ]` -- testing whether `x` is a non-empty string. If they _don't_ expand to single words, then behavior gets even more unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

The XSI extensions `-a` and `-o` are deprecated per [per the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX spec for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/test.html):

> The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. (Many expressions using them are ambiguously defined by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.) Scripts using these expressions should be converted to the forms given below. Even though many implementations will continue to support these obsolescent forms, scripts should be extremely careful when dealing with user-supplied input that could be confused with these and other primaries and operators. Unless the application developer knows all the cases that produce input to the script, invocations like:

Thus, the preferred solution is:

```
if [ "$USER" != root ] || [ "$USER" != XYZ ]; then
```

...though, really, this will *always* be true, since no user can be both `root` and `XYZ` at the same time, so all values will always be true for one side of the `OR` operation or the other. What you really want is to find if it's *neither* of the two, as opposed to whether it's *not one or not the other*:

```
if [ "$USER" != root ] && [ "$USER" != XYZ ]; then
```

---

In shells adopting ksh extensions (including bash and zsh), an extended form of test -- `[[ ]]` -- is also available which allows `&&` and `||` to be used literally, as well as suppressing string-splitting, suppressing glob expansion, and adding new features (pattern matching, regex matching, etc). Thus, if only targeting bash, ksh, or a similarly modern shell, one can also use:

```
if [[ "$USER" != root && "$USER" != XYZ ]]; then
```

Quotes aren't needed here for expansions on the left-hand side of comparisons, because string-splitting and glob expansion (the behaviors those quotes would suppress) are off by default. They're used above simply to demonstrate good habits. (On the right-hand side of comparisons, quotes assert that content is literal, rather than a regex or shell pattern, and thus can be necessary).